# Keeping History when moving Team Projects TFS

Tags: tfs

I am working on a TFS Implementation where the original Project that was created has a cpace in the name. This is causing issue in our builds since we need to kick off a batch file for the Deploy process and the space in the name creates some issues with the path name of the build folder. With this, I want to create a new project without the space. As you can imagine, I would like to keep the revision history of the Source Code if possible.

I have looked at this StackOverflow

[Team Foundation Server - Moving Source with History](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2215593/team-foundation-server-moving-source-with-history)

But I am a bit confused about what I would need to do. Is there someone out there that can point me to a document that is more friendly to someone who doesn't have a lot of TFS experience.

Comment: I would recommend you to fix the path issue by finding a workaround for space issue in your builds instead of moving the team project.

Comment: @Jehan33 is there a way to modify the BuildDefinitionPath from the .xaml file?

Answer (score 0):

We've been faced with a similar task and we've used the [TFS Integration Platform](http://tfsintegration.codeplex.com/) which might be of use to you.

Here's a couple of good blog posts on how to use it:

[TFS Integration Tools - Part 1](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/willy-peter_schaub/archive/2011/10/20/tfs-integration-tools-can-i-migrate-all-work-items-from-one-team-project-collection-to-another.aspx)

[TFS Integration Tools - Part 2](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/willy-peter_schaub/archive/2011/05/13/tfs-integration-tools-where-does-one-start-part-2-try-a-simple-migration.aspx)