# TFS Moving Files with history

Tags: visual-studio-2010, version-control, tfs

**FYI,**

I have gone through this link - **[Team Foundation Server - Moving Source with History](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2215593/team-foundation-server-moving-source-with-history)** which is of different scenario

**Issue:**

We were working in a single solution with multiple projects in **TFS1** before three months, but unfortunately one bad day due to the hardware issue we were not able to use the server.

so during the three months of time we had the backup of files and we created a new tfs server (**TFSNew**) instance and started working. During this three months we split the solution into two solutions with several projects in it and also many added new projects to it.

Now we got the TFS1 instance back and what i need now is i have to migrate the current TFS files along with the History and append the history to the respective files in the **TFS1** Server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to move that history across to the new server. You would need to create some PowerShell that got each change and pushed It into the old location.

This is not a trivial activity and you should consult a professional.

I would just take the tip and check that into the of server.

Comment: Except that there is, it's just painful and tedious.

Comment: So there is no way to "move", only a long painful "migration" 

Answer (score 2):

You could do the following:

1. Merge Team Projects into one in TFS (see [this article](http://nakedalm.com/merge-many-team-projects-one-tfs/)).
2. Do a baseless merge from the New Team Project (you've just brought in) into the new branch.
3. Delete your New branch.

There's a fair degree of risk involved in this process, mostly if you're not working with proper backups & things.  I'd suggest giving it a trial run with one of the smaller projects you're working against, to make sure it goes as expected, or maybe on a whole different TFS install, so you can be sure you've got things figured out before the real deal.

Comment: Sure... I wrote that article and it will not solve the above issue. A baseless merge will not provide the history that was asked for. Better to do a single flat checking at next to zero cost compared with merging TP's first.

Comment: You're saying that baseless merges aren't tracked in terms of history?  This seems kind of dubious - I'd have to see it done, I think.

Comment: The merge is baseless. So the history is ignored and a single checkin performed to "base" the two branches and create a relationship. After that history is tracked, but existing history would look the same as if you just checked in the files without "migrating" history.

Comment: Yes, but the history *in the other branch* would still be there.  You can still access that history - heck, so long as you don't permanently delete the branch, you can still get the history.